# Как сделать кастомный MessageBox

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

Нужно сделать форму, по функционалу напоминающую MessageBox. Другими словами я вызываю статичный метод, который создает форму, останавливает основной код и ожидает нажатия клавиши ГОТОВО.
От стандартного решения, мое будет отличатся наличием ComboBox, в котором юзер должен будет выбрать опцию, которая по нажатию клавиши ГОТОВО, должна быть возвращена, а основной код должен продолжить работу. Вопрос в том, как нам остановить выполнение основного кода, при этом оставив форму для выбора активной. Пробовал Разные способы использования потоков, но ничего не вышло. Привожу пример тестового кода.

```
private void Form1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(UserSelect.userSelectDialog());
        }
```

```
 public static string userSelectDialog(string shop_id = null, string text = "Выбор пользователя:")
        {
            var t1 = new Thread(()=> 
            {
                UserSelect us = new UserSelect(shop_id, text);
            });

            t1.Start();

            while (true);
            return "";   
        }
```

Тут я пытался создать форму в потоке, а основной код остановить бесконечным циклом. Но это не работает, форма, что была создана в потоке тоже не работает. Какие еще варианты?

Comment: `userSelectDialog` - сколько боли в этом методе. Удалите, и не пишите больше такое никогда. А вообще вам нужен `Form.ShowDialog()` вместо `Form.Show()`.

Comment: Все было так просто, безмерно благодарен.

Comment: Просто посмотрите видео https://youtu.be/XWM0VnTXksY - первое же попавшееся по запросу на ютубе "c# custom messageBox"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было всего лишь использовать Form.ShowDialog()

Comment: А если сделаете форме `StartupPosition = CenterParent`, а диалог вызовете с помощью `.ShowDialog(this)`, то она появится в центре родительской формы. А еще можно кнопкам `DialogResult` назначать и получать его из `ShowDialog`, прямо как с месседжбоксом.